# Iterate over a CSV file multiple times using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I am using the following code:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

f = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Tanmay\Desktop\moneycontrol.csv",encoding="ISO-8859-1")
companies = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Tanmay\Desktop\file2.csv",encoding="ISO-8859-1")
count = 0
ld = open(r"C:\Users\Tanmay\Desktop\companyName.csv",'a',encoding="ISO-8859-1")

for companyName,symbol in zip(companies.NAMEOFCOMPANY,companies.SYMBOL):
    count+=1
    if(count%2==0):
        companyNamestr = str(companyName)
        symbolstr = str(symbol)
        print(companyNamestr  + "  " + symbolstr)
        listOfNames = []
        listOfNames.append(companyNamestr)
        listOfNames.append(companyNamestr.lower())
        listOfNames.append(companyNamestr.upper())

        for searchRow in listOfNames:
            print (searchRow + "  ")
            v = f[f.Subtitle.str.contains(searchRow)]
            try:
                v.companyName = companyNamestr
                v.to_csv(ld,header = False)
            except:
                pass   
ld.close()
```

I want to create a file which has all the articles sorted according to the company names, that is if the company name is contained in the subtitle of the news, it should be displayed in the new CSV file. 
But the problem here is if a subtitle contains more than 1 company name, it is not appearing multiple times with every company name. Once it finds the company name, it maps it with that and does not check again. What I am trying to say is that one entry for the news article is appearing only one time even if it has more than 1 company names contained in it.

The moneycontrol.csv file contains all the news articles. This file contains the arrtibute 'Subtitle'.
The file2.csv file contains the list of all companies with the attributes 'NAMEOFCOMPANY' and 'SYMBOL'.
The output file is companyName.csv where one column name is companyName where the name of the company appears multiple times and each entry is associated with one news article.

Comment: can you provide some sample data?

Comment: As a first tip, seperate your program in distinct functions. First extract the different company names and symbols; secondly look for all the news about each of those companies, concatenate this news. PS, you can [`search`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains) case insensitive. PPS. when you use files, use them with a context manager (`with`-statement)

Comment: Curious, I have never seen anything similar to `v = f[f.Subtitle.str.contains(searchRow)]`. I'm just here from review queues, but I have to ask, what does that line do and how does it work?

Comment: The searchRow contains the company name and the Subtitle is the name of the column in my csv file.  We check if the company name in contained in the Subtitle. If yes, then copy the complete row in my new csv file.